# What is the adjective that describes the way someone speaks as if it was obvious?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is my first post so please tell me if I am making any mistakes. I am searching for the word that can be used in a format similar to this:

"asdf," he said in a _____ way.
or 
"asdf," he said ____ly. 
to give the same meaning as "He looked at me as if it were obvious."

I think it's kind of like condescending but instead of pure arrogance also a bit of irritation? I found the term "matter of factly" but that feels like it's mostly just unemotional?

I put this under the single-word-requests because I need a tag but it can also be a phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for **"patronizing"**? (it does not convey the irritation streak, though)
[**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronizing) defines patronizing as

> "showing that you believe you are more intelligent or better than other people."

e.g.

> - She spoke to us in a patronizing tone.
> - A patronizing comment.

from [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/patronizing) - "to behave towards (someone) in a way which is kind and friendly but which nevertheless shows that one thinks oneself to be more important, clever etc than that person."

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!